# XPath - determine if a tree has only one type of a "leaf" node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xpathnavigator

I need an XPath expression that verifies that an XML list element has only a certain type of node.
example:

I need to know if the list has only images.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mc type="group"> 
  <mc type="list"> 
    <mc type="group"> 
      <mc type="image"/> 
    </mc>  
    <mc type="group"> 
      <mc type="image"/> 
    </mc>  
    <mc type="group"> 
      <mc type="image"/> 
    </mc>  
    <mc type="group"> 
      <mc type="image"/> 
    </mc> 
  </mc> 
</mc>
```

the above XML is TRUE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mc type="group"> 
  <mc type="list"> 
    <mc type="group"> 
      <mc type="image"/> 
    </mc>  
    <mc type="group"> 
      <mc type="image"/> 
      <mc type="text"/>
    </mc>  
    <mc type="group"> 
      <mc type="image"/> 
    </mc>  
    <mc type="group"> 
      <mc type="image"/> 
    </mc> 
  </mc> 
</mc>
```

the above XML is FALSE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
not(//mc[not(mc) and @type[not(. = 'image')]])
```

This evaluates to `true()` if and only if there isn't a "leaf" `mc` element the string-value of whose `type` attribute is different from the string `"image"`.

**Explanation**: Proper use of the "*[double-negation law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation)*".

Answer (score 1):

You can check `not(/mc/mc[@type = 'list']//mc[not(@type = 'image')])` if you start with the document node as the context node or `not(.//mc[not(@type = 'image')])` if you start with the `mc` element with the `type="list"` attribute.

Comment: Shouldn't it be not(/mc/mc[@type = 'list']//mc[not(@type = 'image')])?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it should be `image` instead of `list` in the second predicate of the first path respectively in the predicate of the second expression. I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use negation of one-or-more: `not(one-or-more(mc[not(@type = 'image')]))` or some such.

Answer (score 0):

Or the stupid/simple method, check for all mc elements if they are not an image/group/list:

```
not(//mc[not(@type = ("image", "group", "list"))])
```